# Looping over complex JSON objects - Need Logic to get sum of values

Tags: json, algorithm, typescript, logic

I'm consuming below JSON from JENKINS API in Angular app. I'm trying to get sum of values of key `n` from the below JSON. I need a logic to implement in typescript.

the problem is here, the JSON structure keep changing. How can I write a logic to calculate sum of values of key "`n`"

Below are the examples of JSON structure  :

```
{
   "J": [
          {
             "n" : 3,
             "J" : [
                    {
                      "n": 6
                      "J": [
                             {
                             "n": 9
                              }
                           ]
                     }
                   ]
          }
        ]
}
```

sum = 18(3+6+9)

Example:2

```
    {
   "J": [
          {

             "J" : [
                    {

                      "J": [
                             {
                                 "J": [
                                        {
                                           "J": [
                                                  {
                                                    "n": 9
                                                  }
                                                ]
                                        }
                                      ]
                              }
                           ]
                     }
                   ]
          }
        ]
}
```

sum = 9

Answer (score 0):

No need for fancy logic, a simple recursion of [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) would suffice:

```
var sumOfN = function(o) {  
  return (o['J'] || []).reduce((m,x) => { 
    return m + sumOfN(x); 
  }, (o['n'] || 0));
};
```

Example #1:

```js
var data = {
   "J": [
          {
             "n" : 3,
             "J" : [
                    {
                      "n": 6,
                      "J": [
                             {
                             "n": 9
                              }
                           ]
                     }
                   ]
          }
        ]
};

var sumOfN = function(o) {  
  return (o['J'] || []).reduce((m,x) => { 
    return m + sumOfN(x); 
  }, (o['n'] || 0));
};

console.log('result = ' + sumOfN(data));
```

Example #2:

```js
var data = {
  "J": [{
    "J": [{
      "J": [{
        "J": [{
          "J": [{
            "n": 9
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

var sumOfN = function(o) {  
  return (o['J'] || []).reduce((m,x) => { 
    return m + sumOfN(x); 
  }, (o['n'] || 0));
};

console.log('result = ' + sumOfN(data));
```

---

**Update**

Example #3

```js
var data = { "J": [{ "J": [ { "J": [{ "J": [{ "J": [{ "n": 9 }] }] }] }, { "J": [{ "n": 9 }, { "n": 9 } ] } ] }] };

var sumOfN = function(o) {  
  return (o['J'] || []).reduce((m,x) => { 
    return m + sumOfN(x); 
  }, (o['n'] || 0));
};

console.log('result = ' + sumOfN(data));
```

Comment: Thanks @IronGeek, I got one more structure. Can you provide the solution for it?var data = {
  "J": [{
    "J": [
 {
      "J": [{
        "J": [{
          "J": [{
            "n": 9
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
 {
        "J": [{
            "n": 9
          },
    {
            "n": 9
          }
    ]
    }  
 ]
  }]
};

Comment: `var data = {
  "J": [{
    "J": [
 {
      "J": [{
        "J": [{
          "J": [{
            "n": 9
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
 {
        "J": [{
            "n": 9
          },
    {
            "n": 9
          }
    ]
    }  
 ]
  }]
};`

Comment: @Suraj.Nerati I don't understand. My solution above should work for any `( x | { "J": [...x], "n": ? })`. Does it not work for you?

Comment: thanks for your reply. No its not working for the below JSON structure - var data = { "J": [{ "J": [ { "J": [{ "J": [{ "J": [{ "n": 9 }] }] }] }, { "J": [{ "n": 9 }, { "n": 9 } ] } ] }] };

Comment: @Suraj.Nerati Are you sure? I've tested it, and it seems to be working just fine. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive TypeScript solution:

```
type J = {
    n?: number,
    J?: J[]
}

function sum(j: J, acc = 0) {
    if (j.J != null) {
        for (let subJ of j.J) {
            acc = sum(subJ, acc);
        }
    }
    return acc + (j.n ? j.n : 0);
}


console.log(sum({
    "J": [
        {
            "n": 3,
            "J": [
                {
                    "n": 6,
                    "J": [
                        {
                            "n": 9
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})); // 18

console.log(sum({
    "J": [
        {

            "J": [
                {

                    "J": [
                        {
                            "J": [
                                {
                                    "J": [
                                        {
                                            "n": 9
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})); // 9
```